# Does VSTO addin need to add registry entries to Wow6432Node?

Tags: 64-bit, vsto, installshield

I have a VSTO addin which will not install on 32bit machines. (the error popup on install is: "This installation package is not supported by this processor type. Contact your product vendor.")
The addin uses Installshield to do the install.
The application builds with "AnyCPU".
It seems to force to 64bit if anything within installshield references a 64bit.  (eg I have registry entries for my addin which are its Description, friendlyName, LoadBehavior and Manifest.  These are located in HKLM/Software (64bit)/Wow6432Node/Microsoft/Office/Outlook/Addins/myAddin)
I don't really know if this needed?

So my fix is to have two releases... where one doesn't have any 64bit registry references.

How would I fix this? I've been toying around with the notion of ditching Installshield LE and moving to vs2017 with some other installer...

Comment: I use [ClickOnce](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/clickonce-security-and-deployment?view=vs-2017) installer in Visual Studio for my VSTO Addins

Comment: I would love to use ClickOnce, however the organisation uses SCCM to deploy it instead.

Answer (score 2):

> I have a VSTO addin which will not install on 32bit machines.

Do you mean the addin is not loaded by Office? or the install package itself fails to install?

I'll assume the addin is not loaded. I don't know how installshield controls the the [package components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/windows-installer-components) bitness, but I will try to provide an answer that you can apply to any tool, as long as the following options are configurable in the tool.

With MSI packages installing VSTO addins you need to make sure your registry entries end up in the right registry hive, based on the bitness of your installed Office version, not the one of the OS.

So, for machines with Office x86 you have these registry:

- **on x86 OS**: HKLM/Software/Microsoft/Office/Outlook/Addins/myAddin
- **on x64 OS & 32-bit Office**: HKLM/Software/Wow6432Node/Microsoft/Office/Outlook/Addins/myAddin

The two paths above represent a single configuration in your MSI. i.e. if you create a standard MSI that installs the standard x86 registry entries on a 32 bit machine that same MSI will automatically be redirected to Wow6432Node for a x64 machine and everything should work if that machine has a 32-bit office installed.

If you have a x64 machine with a **64-bit office** than you need to force the installation of that registry outside of the Wow6432Node, i.e. directly under: *HKLM/Software/Microsoft/Office/Outlook/Addins/myAddin*

This can be done from a 32-bit MSI too, if you mark the registry MSI component as a 64-bit (don't know where this option is in IS but I am sure you can find it). This will force the OS to stop the redirection to Wow6432Node for those registry entries. And the MSI should also work on 32 bit machines, where this flag will be ignored.

However, you should know that marking the component as 64-bit in a 32 bit MSI package will trigger some [ICE errors/warning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/ice-reference).

> These are located in HKLM/Software (64bit)/Wow6432Node/Microsoft/Office/Outlook/Addins/myAddin)

FYI, this is the 32 bit area of registry on a 64-bit machine, **not** the 64-bit one. Only 32 bit applications can read registry from this location.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  It will take me a while to decipher.  The issue however is that the installer fails to complete.  I've updated the question.

Comment: Got it. As you probably know by now MSI packages can either be x86 or x64 bit, there is no native support for AnyCPU in Windows Installer. 

I don't have that enough experience with IS to help out more, but hopefully my details above can help you sort the problem if you decide to switch to another tool.